# Store procedures gives me error c#

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I am using sql store procedure to get the list of data, but currently I am getting an error as  `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Data.dll`, This program should be able to get data for today's date. This is my modal:

And this my code;

```
   public List<ClassName> GetStaffs()
    {
         List<ClassName> staff = new List<ClassName>();

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.etc...);

        SqlCommand mycomm = new SqlCommand("ProcedureName",connection);
        mycomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        mycomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("dates",DateTime.Today);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        connection.Open();
        reader = mycomm.ExecuteReader();
        connection.Close();
        return staff;
     }
```

In this line I get error `reader = mycomm.ExecuteReader();` I am also not sure if the code will get me the list of staff data I requested. Can someone guide me to the right direction. This is the example I have used [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx)

Store procedure in SQL 2008

```
    USE databaseName
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcedureName] @dates Datetime   

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT ID, fName, sName, dates,   
COUNT(CASE TotalStaff WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE NULL END) AS TotalStaffs, 
FROM dbo.DatabaseName WHERE dates>= @dates  
GROUP BY ID, fName, sName, dates 

END
```

**UPDATE**
I manage to solve the error but i am getting no data from my store procedure.

Comment: What is the purpose of the call to the stored procedure? You don't set the content of the list returned by this method.

Comment: Please add the code for the stored procedure. And - is it really called `ProcedureName` ?

Comment: So what happens if you execute your SP directly against the DB, e.g. using SSMS? Does that return your data OK?

Comment: I dont know much about store procedure. How would I correct the above example? do I just use normal method as public getStaff(){etc..} and return getStaff() method?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line that isn't working and check what the call stack right before the exception is. In case the problem is in your code.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt & @DeanOC I have updated my question, as a example I have called store procedure name as `ProcedureName `

Comment: *1)* You don't do anything with your `reader` so `staff` will always be an empty list. *2)* Where/how do you call `GetStaffs()`?

Comment: @DaveParsons I manage to solve that error, but I am getting no result. How would correct the above example so that I get data that are in my store procedure.

Comment: What is the value of your variable - **@dates** in SP ?? I mean i want to know the date format. and when you pass this parameter to SP at that time, is it contain "Date and Time" both or only "Date" ?

Comment: @KrishnrajRana - [@]date will get today's date and yes its date and time

Comment: @User911 : And what about dates column in Table ?? I mean data stored in this column contain Date and time both Or only "Date" ??? So that i can do some modification in your query.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana yes in dates column the return type is DateTime. How would i correct my c# code because at the moment i am getting empty result.

Comment: @User911 : Let me confirm that Is your SP returns the result ?? If yes that means your SP is correct and something wrong with your code. so just confirm it. Thanks..

Comment: @KrishnrajRana In my database things are returning the result. I think there is a problem with my code. at the moment i am not making a use of store procedure but i am using modal to get the list. How would I make it so that i get list using store procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay in your SP i have ignore the time portion in where condition by casting **"dates"** column in Date. So now your SP look like this -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcedureName] 
@dates Datetime   

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT ID, fName, sName, dates,   
COUNT(CASE TotalStaff WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE NULL END) AS TotalStaffs, 
FROM dbo.DatabaseName WHERE CAST(dates As Date) >= CAST(@dates  As Date)
GROUP BY ID, fName, sName, dates 

END
```

and in your c# code, you have not added object in your list. So here is the modified code.

```
public List<ClassName> GetStaffs()
{
            List<ClassName> staff = new List<ClassName>();

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.etc...);

            SqlCommand mycomm = new SqlCommand("ProcedureName",connection);
            mycomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            mycomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("dates",DateTime.Today);
            SqlDataReader reader;
            connection.Open();
            reader = mycomm.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                staff.Add(new ClassName { fName = Convert.ToString(reader["fName"]), sName = Convert.ToString(reader["sName"]), ..so-on });
            }
            connection.Close();
            return staff;
}
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: @User911 : Glad to help you... Thanks if you can give one up-vote to this answer...